# "Fatal error" when using TikZ externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

So I'm having problems with TikzExternalize. I have a paper with a large amount of dynamically built graphs. I get to a certain point in my files and I can't build anymore. Once I get to this point I can no longer build any of the files I was building earlier, if I comment that figure out it works perfectly again. If I insert a totally different figure it has the same issue. An example code for the figure is below, I'm also using these in a pdfscape and multicolumn environment

Happens with something as simple as the code below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) --(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikzfigures/Report-figure53" "\def\tikzex
ternalrealjob{Report}\input{Report}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 't
ikzfigures/Report-figure53' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please ver
ify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-
escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe
the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikzfigures/Report-
figure53.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

In the file all I get is the usual junk and:

```
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file
produced!
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[]             % options: RDPonly, coveronly, nocover
{article}                       %   plus standard article class options
\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, positioning, calc, external}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzfigures/]

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) --(1,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

        \columnbreak

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) --(1,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

        \columnbreak

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) --(1,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: which tex distribution you are using? May be update is in order!

Comment: Did you check `tikzfigures/Report-figure53.log` as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Perhaps you are running out of space in the device? (unlikely, but...)

Comment: Even if compiling with the `\tikzexternalize` commented out, I get `! Dimension too large.` But it works when commenting out all the `multicols` and `\columnbreak` stuff.

Comment: You have declared that there will be two columns (`\begin{multicols}{2}`) but are trying to have three columns (two occurrences of `\columnbreak`).  I get the same error as you when replacing the `tikzpicture`s by `lipsum` and changing either the number of columns or number of `\columnbreak`s fixes it.

Comment: @AndrewStacey is there a way to do it without getting rid of column breaks or increasing the number of columns? I have a variable number of tables/figures and I'd rather do it without if statements in my for loop

Comment: @Eric I have no idea.  I have never used the `multicol` before so I don't know how flexible it is.  You could try asking that as a new question.

Comment: @AndrewStacey ended up using the if statements. Everything builds perfectly now. Thank you!